# parse a dot seperated string into dictionary variable

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have string values as,

```
"a"
"a.b"
"b.c.d"
```

How to convert them into python dictionary variables as,

```
a
a["b"]
b["c"]["d"]
```

The first part of the string (before dot) will become the dictionary name and the rest of the substrings will become the dictionary keys

Comment: How is the output a dictionary?

Comment: Didn't get the question. What do you actually want to happen? Can you be more specific? Do you want `a` to be a dictionary with key `b`, and then `b` to be a dictionary with key `c` which has a dictionary as value, which has key `d`?

Comment: yes tomasyany... the first part of the string (before dot) will become the dictionary name and the rest of the substrings will become the dictionary keys...

Comment: So `a` will be the variable that stores the dictionary of dictionaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval` is fairly dangerous here, since this is untrusted input. You could use regex to grab the dict name and key names and look them up using `vars` and `dict.get`.

```
import re

a = {'b': {'c': True}}

in_ = 'a.b.c'
match = re.match(
    r"""(?P<dict>      # begin named group 'dict'
          [^.]+        #   one or more non-period characters
        )              # end named group 'dict'
        \.             # a literal dot
        (?P<keys>      # begin named group 'keys'
          .*           #   the rest of the string!
        )              # end named group 'keys'""",
    in_,
    flags=re.X)

d = vars()[match.group('dict')]
for key in match.group('keys'):
    d = d.get(key, None)
    if d is None:
        # handle the case where the dict doesn't have that (sub)key!
        print("Uh oh!")
        break
result = d

# result == True
```

Or even more simply: split on dots.

```
in_ = 'a.b.c'
input_split = in_.split('.')
d_name, keys = input_split[0], input_split[1:]

d = vars()[d_name]
for key in keys:
    d = d.get(key, None)
    if d is None:
        # same as above
result = d
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same problem for parsing ini files with dot-delimited keys in different sections.  e.g.:

```
[app]
site1.ftp.host = hostname
site1.ftp.username = username
site1.database.hostname = db_host
; etc..
```

So I wrote a little function to add "add_branch" to an existing dict tree:

```
def add_branch(tree, vector, value):
    """
    Given a dict, a vector, and a value, insert the value into the dict
    at the tree leaf specified by the vector.  Recursive!

    Params:
        data (dict): The data structure to insert the vector into.
        vector (list): A list of values representing the path to the leaf node.
        value (object): The object to be inserted at the leaf

    Example 1:
    tree = {'a': 'apple'}
    vector = ['b', 'c', 'd']
    value = 'dog'

    tree = add_branch(tree, vector, value)

    Returns:
        tree = { 'a': 'apple', 'b': { 'c': {'d': 'dog'}}}

    Example 2:
    vector2 = ['b', 'c', 'e']
    value2 = 'egg'

    tree = add_branch(tree, vector2, value2)    

    Returns:
        tree = { 'a': 'apple', 'b': { 'c': {'d': 'dog', 'e': 'egg'}}}

    Returns:
        dict: The dict with the value placed at the path specified.

    Algorithm:
        If we're at the leaf, add it as key/value to the tree
        Else: If the subtree doesn't exist, create it.
              Recurse with the subtree and the left shifted vector.
        Return the tree.

    """
    key = vector[0]
    tree[key] = value \
        if len(vector) == 1 \
        else add_branch(tree[key] if key in tree else {},
                        vector[1:],
                        value)
    return tree
```

Comment: Super helpful. I'm using this as a crossover for people to use and excel sheet with columns labeled in this pattern so that I can do bulk api calls though I needed to add a bit to the logic to get it to work: 
 rowObj.update(add_branch(rowObj,colName.split("."),rowValue))

Answer (score 3):

```py
s = "a.b.c"
s = s.replace(".", "][")+"]" # 'a][b][c]'
i = s.find("]") # find the first "]"
s = s[:i]+s[i+1:] # remove it 'a[b][c]'
s = s.replace("]", "\"]").replace("[", "[\"") # add quotations 'a["b"]["c"]'
# you can now execute it:
v = eval(s)
```

Comment: this evaluates to `a[b][c]` as against `a["b"]["c"]`. To solve this, i added two more lines before `eval` as, `s = s.replace("]", "\"]")` and `s = s.replace("[", "[\"")`.

Comment: Oh, I should fix it then

Answer (score 0):

The [pyjq](https://pypi.org/project/pyjq/) library does something quite similar to this, except you have to explicitly provide a dictionary to be the root, and you have to prefix your strings with a `.` to refer to whatever dictionary was your root.

python:

```
import pyjq
d = { 'a' : { 'b' : { 'c' : 'd' } } }
for path in ['.a', '.a.b', '.b.c.d', '.x']:
    print(pyjq.first(path, d))
```

output:

```
{'b': {'c': 'd'}}
{'c': 'd'}
None
None
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party,
but a solution to create the actual dict entries from a dotted path can be done with what is essentially fold-right, where the accumulator starts out as the "leaf" value but changes to a dict after first "iteration" of the reversed path

```py
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> path = 'a.b.c'
>>> leaf_val = 'd'
>>> reduce(lambda accum, val: {val: accum}, reversed(path.split(".")), leaf_val)
{'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}
```

This is not quite what the question asks, but could be worked into the other solution to avoid eval and lengthy recursive function defs