# Convert dot delimited string to json Python

Tags: python, json

i've got a dot delimited string which I need to convert to Json. This is an example with different types of strings:

```
my.dictionary.value -> value
my.dictionary.list[0].value -> value
my.dictionary.list[1].value.list[0].value -> value
```

I have no problems converting the first type of string using a recursive approach:

```
def put(d, keys, item):
    if "." in keys:
        key, rest = keys.split(".", 1)
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = {}
        put(d[key], rest, item)
    else:
        d[keys] = item
```

But i'm struggling to find a solution for the lists. Is there a library that provides out of the box string to json conversion? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there isn't any modules that would do this

Here is a sample code to converted a series of dotted strings into json format. You just have create a new list when you see the pattern `[n]` in the string that would be used as a key.

```
import re
import json

def parse_dotted_strlines(strlines):
    res= {}
    for line in strlines.splitlines():
        parse_dotted_str(line, res)
    return res

def parse_dotted_str(s, res):
    if '.' in s:
        key, rest = s.split('.', 1)
        # Check if key represents a list
        match = re.search(r'(.*)\[(\d)\]$', key)
        if match:
            # List
            key, index = match.groups()
            val = res.get(key, {}) or []
            assert type(val) == list, f'Cannot set key {key} as of type list as i
t was earlier marked as {type(val)}'
            while len(val) <= int(index):
                val.append({})
            val[index] = parse_dotted_str(rest, {})
            res[key] = val
        else:
            # Dict
            res[key] = parse_dotted_str(rest, res.get(key, {}))
    elif '->' in s:
        key, val = s.split('->')
        res[key.strip()] = val.strip()

    return res
```

#### Sample input and output

```
lines = """
my.dictionary.value -> value
my.dictionary.list[0].value -> value
my.dictionary.list[1].value.list[0].value -> value
"""

res = parse_dotted_strlines(lines)
print (json.dumps(res, indent=4))
{
    "my": {
        "dictionary": {
            "value": "value",
            "list": [
                {
                    "value": "value"
                },
                {
                    "value": {
                        "list": [
                            {
                                "value": "value"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `json` package is what you need

```
import json
mydict = """{
    "str1": "str",
    "list1": ["list1_str1", "list1_str2"],
    "list2": ["list2_str1", "list2_str2", ["list2_str11", "list_str12"]]
}"""
json.loads(mydict)
>> {'str1': 'str',
 'list1': ['list1_str1', 'list1_str2'],
 'list2': ['list2_str1', 'list2_str2', ['list2_str11', 'list_str12']]}
```

Comment: You didn't read my question at all, I wasn't asking about how to dump a string

Comment: Yep, but I've updated my answer. I was doing the inverse :) . Is this what you need ?

Comment: No, I need to load a dot separated string as stated in the example :)

Comment: @Weizen can you please provide a minimal runnable example with its input and expected outputs ?

Comment: Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53270227/convert-dot-notation-string-into-nested-python-object-with-dictionaries-and-arra# I need a similar solution but the problem is that the solution stated there doesn't work with something like my.dictionary.list[0] -> value