# How to convert dot separated string into yaml format using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am having a file having some properties myprop.properties

```
a.b.c.d : '0'
a.b.c.e : 'hello'
a.b.c.f : 'hello1'
a.b.g.h : '123'
a.b.g.i : '4567'
http_port : false
install_java : true
```

I want to dump this file into yaml format, so the expected output should be:

```
a:
 b:
  c:
  - d: '0'
    e: hello
    f: hello1
  g:
  - h: '123'
    i: '4567'
http_port : false
install_java : true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert dot notation keys to tree-structured YAML in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163376/convert-dot-notation-keys-to-tree-structured-yaml-in-ruby)

Comment: [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47276490/10197418) might help you, and also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53307100/10197418) for a more refined version.

Comment: How do you know that there has to be a sequence between the key `c` and the key `d` and not between the key `b` and `c`? It would be kind of obvious if your input was `a.b.c.0.d`, `a.b.c.0.e`, etc. but it isn't.

Answer (score 5):

using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47276490/10197418) nice recursive function, you could convert your dotmap string to a dict and then do a `yaml.dump`:

```py
def add_branch(tree, vector, value):
    key = vector[0]
    if len(vector) == 1:
        tree[key] = value  
    else: 
        tree[key] = add_branch(tree[key] if key in tree else {}, vector[1:], value)
    return tree

dotmap_string = """a.b.c.d : '0'
a.b.c.e : 'hello'
a.b.c.f : 'hello1'
a.b.g.h : '123'
a.b.g.i : '4567'
http_port : false
install_java : true"""

# create a dict from the dotmap string:
d = {}
for substring in dotmap_string.split('\n'):
    kv = substring.split(' : ')
    d = add_branch(d, kv[0].split('.'), kv[1])

# now convert the dict to YAML:
import yaml    
print(yaml.dump(d))  
# a:
#   b:
#     c:
#       d: '''0'''
#       e: '''hello'''
#       f: '''hello1'''
#     g:
#       h: '''123'''
#       i: '''4567'''
# http_port: 'false'
# install_java: 'true'
```

Comment: @MM I've seen your edit suggestion: it seems like a substantial change to me, so maybe you want to add this as a separate answer? I don't want to take credit for your work here, so I rejected the edit suggestion.